# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, discord, attributeerror

I'm a python beginner and recently I've been trying to develop a bot for discord. The problem is that I've been getting the following error when I type the command `"!new"`:

```
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 71, in on_message
    update_encouragements(encouraging_message)
  File "main.py", line 32, in update_encouragements
    encouragements.append(encouraging_message)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I already tried to rewrite the update_encouragement function and the encouragement.append but I can't get out of this error. I'm out of ideas on how to solve this.

This is my code

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from replit import db

client = discord.Client()

sad_words = [
    "sad", "depressed", "unhappy", "angry", "miserable", "depressing"
]

starter_encouragements = [
    "Cheer up!",
  "Hang in there.",
  "You are a great person / bot!"
]

if "responding" not in db.keys():
  db["responding"] = True

def get_quote():
  response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
  return (quote)

def update_encouragements(encouraging_message):
  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    encouragements.append(encouraging_message)
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements
  else:
    db["encouragements"] = [encouraging_message]


def delete_encouragement(index):
  encouragements = db ["encouragements"]
  if len(encouragements) > index:
    del encouragements[index]
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  msg = message.content

  if msg.startswith('!inspire'):
    quote = get_quote()
    await message.channel.send(quote)

  if db["responding"]:
    options = starter_encouragements
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      (options) += str(db["encouragements"])

  if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(options))

  if msg.startswith("!new"):
      encouraging_message = msg.split("!new", 1)[1]
      update_encouragements(encouraging_message)
      await message.channel.send("new encouraging message added.")

  if msg.startswith("!del"):
    encouragements = []
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      index = int(msg.split("!del",1)[1])
      delete_encouragement(index)
      encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    await message.channel.send(encouragements)
  if msg.startswith("!lista"):
    encouragements = []
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    await message.channel.send(encouragements)

  if msg.startswith("!responding"):
    value =  msg.split("!responding ",1)[0]

    if value.lower() == "true":
      db["encouragements"] = True
      await message.channel.send("Responding is on.")
    else:
      db["encouragements"] = False
      await message.channel.send("Responding is off.")
```

Comment: read the error message carefully: in the line `encouragements.append(encouraging_message)`, ` encouragements` is a boolean value, not a list, so it doesn't have an `append` method. The answer to your question lies in why you  thought it was a list in the first place. Are you using the wrong variable? Or was that variable actually a list that got overwritten with a boolean at some point of the program?

Comment: You have both `db["encouragements"] = [encouraging_message]` and `db["encouragements"] = True` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.content` method on line 32. They `encouragements` keywords is a boolean value that returns a `true` or `false` statement. So you can fix it by changing line 32 to:

```
encouragements.append(encouraging_message.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that the `encouragements` variable is bool.

check out `dir(encouragements)` to check which methods you can use on this object to get a list object